# Legend does not come in bold in firefox and chrome for highcharts with pie

Tags: firefox, highcharts

Below is my code for a pie chart:

```
legend: { margin: 1, padding: 4, layout: 'horizontal', align: 'center', verticalAlign: 'bottom', itemWidth: 189, borderWidth: 0, enabled: true, useHTML: false, labelFormatter: function () { return (this.y == 0 || this.y == null || this.y == '') ? "" : (this.name); }, itemMarginBottom: 8, itemStyle: { color: '#333333', fontWeight: 'bold', fontFamily: 'Arial', fontSize: '10px', lineHeight: '15px' }, symbolWidth: 11, x: -7, symbolPadding: 8 }
```

However the legend text is not bold till i change the font to 10.5 which i think is too big.

Below is the html generated in FF:THis happens in both Chrome and Firefox. IE is working fine.

```
<text x="19" y="13" style="font-family:Arial;font-size:10.4px;cursor:pointer;color:#333333;font-weight:bold;line-height:15px;fill:#333333;" text-anchor="start" zIndex="2">
```

Is there something I can do about this?

Answer (score 0):

For me it is bolded, compare: http://jsfiddle.net/3bQne/233/

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container2'
    },
    legend: {
        margin: 1,
        padding: 4,
        layout: 'horizontal',
        align: 'center',
        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
        itemWidth: 189,
        borderWidth: 0,
        enabled: true,
        useHTML: false,
        labelFormatter: function () {
            return (this.y == 0 || this.y == null || this.y == '') ? "" : (this.name);
        },
        itemMarginBottom: 8,
        itemStyle: {
            color: '#333333',
            //fontWeight: 'bold',
            fontFamily: 'Arial',
            fontSize: '10px',
            lineHeight: '15px'
        },
        symbolWidth: 11,
        x: -7,
        symbolPadding: 8
    },

    series: [{
        showInLegend: true,
        type: 'pie',
        data: [3.45, 4.21, 5.11]
    }]
});
```

And image: [image: compare in Chrome]

Comment: I am able to see the problem in Chrome in the jsFiddle as well! wish I could post a screenshot

Comment: In your screenshot the first chart has a px of? I can see the top one is bold and the one below is not. When I open the jsFiddle I can see my issue is reproduced. Any idea why this could be? And the font looks really different in all browsers. IE is the only browser where it looks decent.

Comment: Not sure what else can I do. Maybe you don't have some fonts? Or could you tell me what OS you have?

Comment: An observation I made is.. Verdana is coming bold in 8px as well. But arial/Helvetica do not come bold till 10.5px. My OS is Windows server 2008 R2 Standard. 64 bit